# How to display retrieved data from JavaScript through html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this seems kind of vague, but it was the best way I could put this into words. Below is the example of my code.

**JavaScript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var name = $('#firstName').val();
        var email = $('#userEmail').val();
        var json = { Email: email, FirstName: name };
        var string = JSON.stringify(json);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://uBuildRewards.api/api/Users/GetInfo',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: string
        });
     </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="user-logged-in">
   <div class="content">
       <div class="user-name" id="firstName"> **NAME HERE** <span class="text-muted f9">admin</span></div>
       <div class="user-email" id="userEmail"> **EMAIL HERE** </div> 
       <div class="user-actions">
           <a class="m-r-5" href="">settings</a> <a href="/first/login">logout</a>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Before all this, in another view I have similar JavaScript code that is doing my login. Which is accessing a method from the UsersController that gets all information, and if email and pass is correct it logs me in. Then, this method, is when I am logged in I want it to say that Welcome, (name of user logged in as) and your current email address is (who ever I am logged in as).

So I am trying to find out how, from the javascript, to paste the info retrieved from the 'GetInfo' method, and display the Name and Email where I put "**NAME HERE** and **EMAIL HERE**"

I tried to be as descriptive as I possibly could. Sorry for any confusion. I greatly appreciate your help in advance :) Still fairly new to JQuery and JavaScript!

Comment: Here ya go (it's a search, not just a link to google.com): https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+display+javascript+string+in+html&oq=how+to+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i65l3j69i57j69i59.1168j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

Comment: That's not a database! That's an attempt to fetch a `json` output from a non-existing website!

Comment: Hmmm, I guess what I am trying to say is.. I am retrieving the data from JavaScript, and I want to know how to display that data through html.

Answer (score 0):

why are you sending login credentials over http and not https (SSL)?

That aside...

You have to use `.done` method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://uBuildRewards.api/api/Users/GetInfo',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true
}).done(function(data) {
      console.log("Sample of data:", data);
      $('#firstName').text(data.name);
      $('#userEmail').text(data.email);

});
```

Comment: Ohhh okay, I see how that works. I think what is happening now is my data that is being retrieved from one view is not transferring over to the other view. For instance, on my `login.cshtml` i have code that takes in email and password and then transfers me by `location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';` on `success: function(data)` Any idea on how to transfer that data over to the `Index.cshtml` view